# How to display line numbers as well as enable copy to system clipboard in vim?

Tags: linux, macos, vim

Local OS: Mac High Sierra

Remote OS: Linux, Debian

In vim, I'd like to enable displaying line numbers as well as enabling copy to system clipboard on both Mac and Linux. At this moment, I created the same .vimrc file in both systems with the below configurations:

> ```
> set number " display line numbers
> set mouse=a
> ```

I also tried `set mouse=r` and `set mouse=v` as suggested in other posts, the issue was not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The local clipboard and the remote clipboard need to be synchronized for this to work. From [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/96180b5b8e7722a7428c):

### On the Mac

1. Make sure you have a clipboard-aware Vim build. I recommend [MacVim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases).
2. Install or update [XQuartz.app](http://www.xquartz.org/) and start it.
3. In the Preferences window, activate clipboard synchronization.
4. Quit XQuartz.app.
5. In iTerm.app or Terminal.app, connect to your remote machine with:

   ```
   $ ssh -X username@host
   ```

   and see the XQuartz.app icon pop-up in your Dock.

From now on, XQuartz.app will start automatically in the background when you use the `-X` flag, taking care of the clipboard synchronization for you.

### On the remote machine

1. If you don't already have it, install GVim. On Debian-based systems, use:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
   ```

   The idea is *not* to use Gvim but installing it gets you everything you need to get clipboard sharing to work:

   - a minimal X
   - a Vim built with clipboard support
2. In Vim, synchronize the *unnamed* and *clipboard* registers by adding this line to `~/.vimrc`:

   ```
   set clipboard^=unnamed
   ```